# How to export images through Layout Manager by switching the display of categorized render one by one

Tags: pyqgis, export, image, batch, categorized-renderer

I recently started using QGIS to create distribution maps of organisms. OS is Windows 10, and QGIS version is 3.24.1.

[image]

What I want to do is how to export a large number of images by switching the display of classified symbols one by one through the layout manager.

I loaded the csv text files into QGIS and categorized them by organism species. I want to switch the display of each species, one at a time, and generate images one after the other. Image generation must pass through Layout Manager.

I am facing a particular difficulty in showing and hiding subgroups: to select a group in the Root (in this case the csv file itself, in this case SpeciesList, or the vector data of the map), I can write `QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)`, but I don't know how to select a subgroup (in this case SpeciesXX).

The code to generate an image of only one species is as follows:

```
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName("LayoutManagerName")
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToImage("C:/Users/XXXX/XXXX/Species001.png", QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the subnodes of a categorized symbol layer using [`layerLegendNodes`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeModel.html#a0cdf799edb85773e073f7b5f73a63e82) function.

A fully working example including the code to export an image will look like the following:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer_node = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer)

manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
model = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel()
legend_nodes = model.layerLegendNodes(layer_node)

# makes sure all categories are unchecked to begin
for ln in legend_nodes:
    ln.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
    
# iterate through each category and export layout
for ln in legend_nodes:
    ln.setData(Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
    name = ln.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
    
    layout = manager.layoutByName("Layout1")
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    settings = QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
    path = fr'D:\Documents\test\{name}.png'
    exporter.exportToImage(path, settings)

    ln.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
```